# User Controller not correctly applying devise's before_filter authenticate_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have explicitly called a `before_filter` to authenticate users before every controller action.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

class UsersController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

If, when I am logged out, I attempt to access any page, I am redirected to the `sign_in` page UNLESS that page is rendered by the `UsersController`.

If that happens, I am granted access to that page UNLESS I'm accessing the `edit` action.

I don't know why `authenticate_user!` is not working in `UsersController` and I'm even more stumped as to why it does work if I access `edit`.

Below is `edit` in `UsersController` (and another method)

```
class UsersController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  #redirects queries as expected
  def edit
      @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
  end

  #Does not redirect queries
  def about
      @user = current_user
  end
```

Does anyone know how I can get the expected behavior (redirection for all queries made to any action in `UsersController`?

Comment: show us the logs of whats happening when you hit the about action.

Comment: @sevenseacat, check this pastie: http://pastie.org/9503328

Comment: looks like there is some issue with the action itself , please do post the logs as said by @sevenseacat

Comment: The action doesn't seems to get the user firstname , do post the related code to it . Problem is with the view file of about page

Comment: @CaffeineCoder, the answer below works, I just have to wait a few minutes to accept it because of Stack Overflow's rules.

Comment: Glad you had it solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add your action to controllers prepend_before_filter:

```
class UsersController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  prepend_before_filter :authenticate_scope!, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy, :about]
  ...
```